# my geolocation(javascript) does not work and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, dictionary, geolocation

I am eventually trying reverse geolocation, however before doing that I want to make sure my geolocation works fine but no luck with my code.

what I am doing is that when user clicks button, my javascript shows latitude and longitude numbers if user agrees with it.

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  var elMap =document.getElementById("showWhere");
  var msg ='Sorry, we were unable to get your location';

    if(Modernizr.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation(success, fail);
    elMap.textContent = 'Checking location...';
  } else {
    elMap.textContent = msg;
  }

    function success(position){
    msg = '<h3>Lng: <br>';
    msg += position.coords.longtitude + '</h3>';
    msg +='<h3>lat: <br>';
    msg+=position.coords.latitude + '</h3>';
    elMap.innerHTML = msg;
  }

    function fail(msg){
    elMap.textContent = msg;
    console.log(msg.code);
  }
 });
```

I thought it is my click function problem and remove this part but it still does not work. What did I miss? Thank you for in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No need to use Modernizr.

```
if ('geolocation' in navigator)
```

2) It's `getCurrentPosition`

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
```

3) Make sure you spell `longitude` correctly.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/trz7t1uu/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I fixed it as you mentioned and now I am trying to make 'click' work :D. Does it not work if I do not put this JS on live? I check it in chrome and it just keep showing 'checking location' message.

Comment: I figured out that I have to change setting for my local files. I have to allow them use my local info for local files.